# Get hash values from SQL Server and Oracle and compare them?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hash

Is it possible to generate hash code from both database server and compare them? How to write the following pseudo SQL in SQL Server? Especially the two `getHash` functions which accept mutliple numeric/float columns in SQL server and oracle.

```
select s.PK
from sqltable s
    join openquery(oracleLinkedServer, 
      'select PK, getHash(Column1, floatColumn2, ..., floatColumnN) oracleHash 
       from oracleTable') o on o.PK = s.PK
where
    getHash(Column1, floatColumn2, ..., floatColumnN) <> oracleHash
```

Comment: Given that many of the datatypes between SQL Server and Oracle are unlikely to have 100% matching representations, it's unlikely to work

Comment: it may work if you convert all values to a big string (x, 1.234, 2.345 = "x1.2342.345") and then compute hash based on same encoding (md5 for example).

Comment: @tbone concatenate them to a big string may introduce more uncertainty.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agreed. I am doing this to avoid to pull too many data from remote server because of slow connection.

Comment: @NickW I'm fairly sure that given the same input string, an Oracle implementation of md5 will give same 32 hex value as SQL Server implementation (assuming no use of random numbers or random salts).  I don't have access to SQL Server, but I'd challenge u to prove this wrong.

Comment: @tbone I tried @Nathan Skerl's answer and was unable to get the same results.  On Oracle I used `select DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash(CONVERT('A', 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8'), 2/*dbms_crypto.HASH_MD5*/) from dual;` (replace UTF8 with your character set) and got the result `68B329DA9893E34099C7D8AD5CB9C940`.  On SQL Server I ran `SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'A');` and got the result `f8VicOenD6gaWTW3Lqy+KQ==`.  For SQL Server access I used http://data.stackexchange.com/, which I believe is using ISO-8859-1, so there shouldn't be character set issues.

Comment: @tbone  This implies to me that Oracle and SQL Server will never match.  But I know almost nothing about SQL Server, I could be doing something very wrong.

Comment: @jonearles I'll see if I can get access to SQL Server, but your 2nd result is NOT a hex representation (0-9 A-F).  Let me see what I can find

Comment: @jonearles see my answer for details

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
select upper(substring(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(hashbytes('MD5','A')),3,32));
```

result:

```
7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29
```

In Oracle :

```
select rawtohex(
    DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash (
        UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('A', 'AL32UTF8'),
        2)
    ) from dual;
```

result:

```
7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29
```

Make sure your strings are exactly the same (case sensitive).  Here I used 'A' as a simple example, but it could be any string really.

If you avoid data type differences by converting to a big string, you should be able to produce the same md5 hash on different platforms.  Note that SQL Server prepended a '0x' to the hash to denote hex representation, which I stripped with the substring.

Comment: Thanks. In my case i have changed AL32UTF8 for AL16UTF16LE on Oracle side and cast the text on MS SQL side to nvarchar ( cast('ĄĘA' as nvarchar(max) ) but anyway many thanks for this.

Comment: How can I get the hash for the entire row instead of just the column?

Comment: @Aravindh You can concatenate strings, but it sounds like you want a unique hash/id for a row, which means you should look into [sys_guid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864575/should-i-use-oracles-sys-guid-to-generate-guids/11865036#11865036)

Comment: @tbone In my case I want to compare rows between sql server and oracle and I dont think GUID will help since I cant generate them on the sql server side as well?

Comment: @Aravindh in that case, pick the columns that would best represent uniqueness in the row and concatenate them into 1 big string (of a reasonable size, say up to 4000).  You'd convert dates to strings of course.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you have [hashbytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx); in  Oracle you have [DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1002022). You should be able to use them to calc an MD5 hash on both sides, though I am not positive the hashes will match... its worth a shot.

There are other ways to compare tables but to answer your question these are the two native functions on either platform.

Comment: These two functions don't accept multiple columns so users had to combine multiple columns into one. Yes, as you mentioned, it's not sure if the hashed values match even if they values are the same, especially for these float number.

Comment: @NickW If you want to hash multiple columns at the same time, on Oracle you can use DBMS_SQLHASH: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixb.htm   But I think that package is very unlikely to match any output from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHECKSUM()` in SQL Server to compute a multi-column hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited access to the Oracle system, and haven't been granted execute permissions on `DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash()`, you can still use `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5()` to generate the same hashed value on both Oracle and SQL Server. You just have to make sure to convert the string to the same code page as the machine running SQL Server. I believe the default on most North American Windows boxes is `windows-1252    ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)` (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/code-page-identifiers)

I don't particularly like having function calls in my `WHERE` clauses, so I put the SQL side hash into a CTE, and then join to the `OPENQUERY` results.

```
;WITH sqlHash AS
(
    SELECT s.PK
        ,UPPER(CONVERT(CHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', s.Column1 + '|' + s.Column2 + '|' + s.ColumnN), 2)) AS sqlHash
    FROM sqltable s
)
SELECT s.PK
FROM sqlHash s
JOIN OPENQUERY
     ( oracleLinkedServer, '
     SELECT 
        PK
        ,CONVERT(UPPER(RAWTOHEX(
            SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string => "oraColumn1" || ''|'' || "oraColumn2" || ''|'' || "oraColumnN")
            )),''AL32UTF8'',''WE8MSWIN1252'') AS oracleHash
       FROM oracleTable' ) o ON o.PK = s.PK
WHERE s.sqlHash <> o.oracleHash
```

A couple of things to point out here that might not be immediately apparent.

First, I'm adding a pipe character, `|`, between each column in the concatenated text. This is differentiate combinations like `"digital" + "aaron"` and `"digi" + "talaaron"` from producing the same hash, as the string would become `"digital|aaron"` and `"digi|talaaron"` which should produce different hashed values.

Second, when we get the SQL side has in the CTE, the value comes back as a `VARBINARY`. If we just displayed this value, there would be a leading `0x`. But we want to strip this off, and also convert the value to something a bit more useful than a `VARBINARY`. So we convert to `CHAR(32)` with a style of `2`.