# How to implement hashing between Oracle, SQL Server, and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle, security, hash

I need to get some sensitive data from an Oracle server to a SQL Server for use in my ASP.NET website. Lets say its passwords. Our security guys say that these passwords need to be secured every step of the way. My website needs to be able to compare user input to these passwords. These passwords must be transferred from the Oracle server to SQL Server at night and can only be used on SQL Server during the day.

The best solution I can come up with is that we need to hash the passwords on Oracle and pass the hashes to SQL Server (lets assume the connection between the two is secure, because that's not my job :P ). Then my ASP.NET web application needs to be able to implement the exact same hashing on user input so we can compare the input hash to the database hash.

So my question is: how can I hash something using the same algorithm/key/salt on Oracle and .NET?  I know how to use the .NET hashing functions, but I'm not sure what I can use in Oracle that would be comparable...  I could potentially pass them in plain text from ASP.NET to SQL Server and hash them there if that's easier, but lets call that "Plan B".

Comment: Why do the databases need to care about the hashing algorithm? The databases should never even receive the raw data being hashed. Your application should be taking care of that.

Comment: @vcsjones - Good question.  The passwords are getting into Oracle from a different source.  My application won't ever see the source, so it can't be the one to hash them in the first place.

Comment: If md5 works for you, see my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810471/get-hash-values-from-sql-server-and-oracle-and-compare-them/8835412#8835412

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your datastore should be storing hashed values, on the asp.net side you'll need to implement an md5 function to convert strings to the hash, and then compare against the hashed value in your db.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_obtool.htm#i1003449

Oracle does have the ability to use MD5 hash, which you can pass to SQL server and implement, as well as ASP.net.

SQL Server md5

http://www.lazerwire.com/2011/10/ms-sql-md5-hash.html

ASP.net MD5

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'll point out that MD5 is somewhat broken, and seems to be getting more broken every day. SHA-256 is really the standard hashing algorithm to be used for this type of purpose these days but it looks like Oracle doesn't support that right now. They do, however, support SHA-1, which is much better than MD5.

Comment: thanks for that information, looking at SHA-1, what are your feeling on TripleDES? We use that here in a few applications that have the need to be able to decrypt.

Comment: TripleDES is an encryption algorithm and not a hashing algorithm. When dealing with passwords, it's best practice to always use a hash of a password (since you cannot unhash something) instead of an encrypted form of the password (since you can decrypt something), if that works. Here, since you only care IF the submitted password matches the stored one, and not WHAT the password actually is, hashes are preferred.

Comment: Right, I knew that TripleDES was encryption and not hashing. Obviously if you hash something you don't want it decrypted. My question was more a general one of the preferred method of encrypting strings that you will later need to decrypt. I'll leave that here, no need to get into a conversation in the comments :)