# Should I use Oracle's sys_guid() to generate guids?

Tags: oracle, primary-key, guid

I have some inherited code that calls `SELECT SYS_GUID() FROM DUAL` each time an entity is created. This means that for each insertion there are two calls to Oracle, one to get the `Guid`, and another to insert the data.

I suppose that there may be a good reason for this, for example - Oracle's Guids may be optimized for high-volume insertions by being sequential and thus they maybe are trying to avoid excessive index tree re-balancing.

Is there a reason to use `SYS_GUID` as opposed to building your own `Guid` on the client?

Comment: Can I put it a different way? You should probably not build your own GUID when there's a native implementation. That's not a reason to use `sys_guid()` necessarily though. It's a lot slower than using a sequence and is a raw data-type, which is more annoying to work with than a simple numbre. If this is only in one DB why can't you just use a single sequence for everything?

Comment: I should be clear that all the languages I know which are used on the Client have GUID types. So, a new Guid in C# is created by Guid.NewGuid() and in java the same is created by UUID.ramdomUUID(). When I say 'build my own' I don't mean writing reams of code, but rather creating a new Guid. Since Guids are guaranteed to be unique, it should not make a difference as to where they are created.

The question relates only to the relative benefit of creating your Guids in Oracle as opposed to the client. 

I know that there are (programatically expensive) ways to create the guid in Oracle on insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found no reason to generate a Guid from Oracle. The round trip between Oracle and the client for every Guid is likely slower than the occasional index rebalancing that occurs is random value inserts.

Answer (score 7):

Why roll your own if you already have it provided to you.  Also, you don't need to grab it first and then insert, you can just insert:

```
create table my_tab
(
val1 raw(16),
val2 varchar2(100)
);

insert into my_tab(val1, val2) values (sys_guid(), 'Some data');
commit;
```

You can also use it as a default value for a primary key:

```
drop table my_tab;
create table my_tab
(
val1 raw(16) default sys_guid(),
val2 varchar2(100),
primary key(val1)
);
```

Here there's no need for setting up a before insert trigger to use a sequence (or in most cases even caring about val1 or how its populated in the code).

More maintenance for sequences also. Not to mention the portability issues when moving data between systems.

But, sequences are more human friendly imo (looking at and using a number is better than a 32 hex version of a raw value, by far). There may be other benefits to sequences, I haven't done any extensive comparisons, you may wish to run some performance tests first.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the relative benefits of sequences over Guids. One of these benefits is that primary keys, especially clustered primary keys benefit from sequential data (not necessarily an integer/numeric sequential type) because the algorithms are optimised to avoid btree rebalancing. It is apparently difficult/impossible to do the same with ramdom data - as in our GUID. However, sys_guid() looks pretty sequential, although the sequence is 'in the middle' of the guid. Hence the question.

Answer (score 4):

If your concern is two database calls, you should be able to call `SYS_GUID()` within your `INSERT` statement. You could even use a `RETURNING` clause to get the value that Oracle generated, so that you have it in your application for further use.

Comment: Thank you, the two calls are one of my concerns. I know that I can generate the Guid along with the insert, but this is programatically expensive.

Comment: I want to know whether a defensible reason exists to choose to have all your Guid primary keys created on the server, instead of on the client.

Comment: Anything is defensible with enough self-delusion ;). I would say you are welcome to generate GUIDs anywhere without people saying you did it "wrong." Honestly, there are some cases where creating GUIDs in the client make sense. If you are doing bulk loads, or need the GUIDs consistent between multiple tables or data sets. Perhaps also if you are working between different databases you may not want to create GUIDs in each system independently. I don't know what you mean by "programatically expensive" though.

Answer (score 3):

SYS_GUID can be used as a default value for a primary key column, which is often more convenient than using a sequence, but note that **the values will be more or less random and not sequential.** On the plus side, that may reduce contention for hot blocks, but on the minus side your index inserts will be all over the place as well. We generally recommend against this practice.

for reference  [click here](http://psoug.org/definition/SYS_GUID.htm)